# Kubernetes MetalLB vs NodePort vs Ingress,what are pros and cons?

Tags: kubernetes, ingress

I have my app(PERN stack),I will deploy it to self-hosted Kubernetes cluster.
I used Ingress before but I saw that some engineers prefer now MetalLB touting its easy set-up,scaling capabilities.
I would like to hear opinion of other fellow engineers.
From [Getting started with MetalLB, the bare metal load balancer for Kubernetes](https://www.spectrocloud.com/blog/getting-started-with-metallb-the-bare-metal-load-balancer-for-kubernetes/)

- Easy to scale: MetalLB automates most aspects of traffic management, and unlike NodePort and ExternalIP, it requires minimal changes to your configurations. It can thus scale to support mappings for dozens or even hundreds of applications, if you need.
- Consistent with cloud-based load balancing: Because MetalLB uses LoadBalancer Service configurations rather than specialized routing methods like NodePort, you can configure MetalLB in a very similar fashion to configuring load balancing in any public cloud-based Kubernetes environment

What does that really mean? Ingress can not scale?

Comment: it's going to be impossible to answer this question without narrowing down the scope a bit. What are your criteria for evaluation? Requesting opinions, while perhaps useful, is definitely going to get the question closed :)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.